# how to remove the gap between the inline-block elements

Tags: css, gaps-in-visuals

```css
.item-list {
  letter-spacing: -0.3em;
}
.item-list a {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <a href="#">a</a>
</div>
```

only in win ie6,the gap between `a`  is still exit ,the style `letter-spacing:-0.3em` will make effective when delete the style of `a { letter-spacing:0 }`

why? can i figure out this problem?

Answer (score 13):

wow this one stumped me for a while...believe it or not here is your answer:

**font-size:0; must be added to parent element**

In the case of your example, I would define the font-size of the a tags separately, and add "font-size:0;" to the parent div element

In other words:

css:

.item-list{letter-spacing:-0.3em; font-size:0;}

.item-list a{letter-spacing:0;display:inline-block; font-size:SOMETHING HIGHER;}

(also your DOCTYPE declaration must be correct or display inline-block can have problems working in IE, at least I had trouble with it with IE7)

This should end any extra margin frustration you're experiencing from display:inline-block;

Comment: tks,bu i had tried this,it still have gap in win ie6,even if the gap is smaller.i use word-spacing:-0.5em (or some else value,it has relation to font),it works,you can have a test.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with how you're typing your HTML. Because you're formatting it nicely in your IDE, a la, with spaces and new lines, those spaces and newlines show up when displayed on the page. So instead of

```
<div class="item-list">

    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">a</a>

</div>
```

type it out as one line and they will go away:

```
<div class="item-list"><a href="#">a</a><a href="#">a</a><a href="#">a</a><a href="#">a</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this CSS

```
a{float:left}
```

Gap will Remove

Comment: I have the same issue, the `float:left` break center align 

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
    line-height: 2.2; //or whatever value you want
```

I took from facebook layout and works amazing for me

Comment: it looks like ,you misunderstanding my meaning.